# Renaming image to product id with php

Tags: php, mysql, image, rename

Im trying to rename an image to the product id using php.

This code currently does save the image but it does not rename the file to id.jpg. 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg etcetc instead it is just .jpg

How do i get it in accordance to the ID.

```
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

    $product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    $price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);

    $details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
    $stock = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stock']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_name='$product_name' LIMIT 1");
    $productMatch = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productMatch > 0) {
        echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Product Name" into the system, <a href="inventory_list.php">click here</a>';
        exit();
    }
    // Add this product into the database now
    $sql = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO products (product_name, price, details, category, stock, date_added) 
        VALUES('$product_name','$price','$details','$category', $stock, now())") or die (mysql_error());
     $pid = mysqli_insert_id($pid);
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "inventory_images/$newname");
    header("location: list.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to give the `$link` from your `mysqli_query` to the [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).
So the following line:

```
$pid = mysqli_insert_id($pid);
```

must be:

```
$pid = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

Check your PHP Error Settings. 
You should have seen an appropriate Error since you've given an undefined variable to a method expecting an mysqli link.

Comment: Cheers, always miss these silly mistakes!

Comment: @user3411002: You're welcome. Since this question is least likely to ever give any value to anyone on this plattform ever again, you might consider deleting it since it is only a typo error.

Comment: Cant delete. Wont let me haha flagged it though.

Comment: @user3411002 Flagging your own question is a very high form of self criticism :D

Comment: I love to criticize myself, helps me improve :D

Comment: @user3411002 still thou: consider accepting my answer to prevent your solved question from getting more unneccessary attention